# Discord JS: Links returned undefined for reddit

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm making a reddit command in discord.js that obtains link from specified subreddit. I'm really concerned about this error. It returned "undefined" in the links instead. I'm not sure that this question already asked before, but therefore I'm sorry if I asked the question again.
Here's the code.

```
   const request = require('request');
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');
    module.exports = {
        name: "reddits",
        description: "Sends a random link from reddit",
        execute(message, args) {
            const subreddits = [
                "aww",
                "memes",
                "funny",
                "pics",
                "gifs",
                "gaming",
                "movies",
                "music",
                "videos",
                "news",
                "worldnews",
                "politics",
                "science",
                "technology",
                "books",
                "programming",
                "television",
                "pcmasterrace",
                "gaming",
                "askreddit",
                "worldnews",
                "todayilearned",
                "aww",
                "pics",
                "gifs",
                "movies",
                "music",
                "videos",
                "news",
                "worldnews",
                "politics",
                "science",
                "technology",
                "books",
                "programming",
                "television",
                "pcmasterrace",
                "gaming",
                "askreddit",
                "worldnews",
                "todayilearned",
                "aww",
                "pics",
                "gifs",
                "movies",
                "music",
                "videos",
                "news",
                "worldnews",
                "politics",
                "science",
                "technology",
                "books",
                "programming",
                "television",
                "pcmasterrace",
                "gaming",
                "askreddit",
                "worldnews",
                "todayilearned",
                "aww",
                "pics",
                "gifs",
                "movies",
                "music",
                "videos",
                "news",
                "worldnews",
                "politics",
                "science",
                "technology",
                "books",
                "programming",
                "television",
                "pcmasterrace",
                "gaming",
                "askreddit",
                "worldnews",
                "todayilearned",
                "aww",
                "pics",
                "gifs",
                "movies",
                "music",
                "videos",
                "news",
                "worldnews",
                "politics",
                "science"
            ];
            const random = subreddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subreddits.length)];
            const subreddit = `https://www.reddit.com/r/${random}/random.json`;
            request(subreddit, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error:', error);
                }
                // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
                console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    // Parse the document body
                    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    const img = $('data').attr('url');
                    message.channel.send(`https://www.reddit.com/${img}`);
                    message.author.send("You have recently used the command 'reddits'. If you have any feedbacks or encounter problems, please contact the developer of this bot. Thank you!");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And here's the output:

[Reddit link return undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO3Ub.png)

Any solutions would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do here? Why do you use cheerio for a JSON file?

Comment: I copied this code from the previous one. But the previous one does require cheerio, but doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the response from the reddit API as JSON. To do that first you will need to parse the body with `JSON.parse(body)`.

```js
request(subreddit, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    }
    // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
    console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Parse the document body
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(body)
        
        console.log(jsonData[0].data.children[0].data) // find what you need from the response json
        
        const img = jsonData[0].data.children[0].data.url;
        console.log(img);
    }
});
```

Note: I'm not sure if this is what you wanted to get so I put a `console.log` of the response json where you can see the reddit post's information and find the one you need.